# How to Validate a dynamic Textbox control

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, dynamic

I have a dynamically created textboxes as (For ex.)

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    TextBox txtControl = new TextBox();
    txtControl.ID = "txt" + i;
    txtControl.AutoPostBack = true;
    txtControl.TextChanged += txtControl_TextChanged;
}
```

I want to validate that the textboxes input is always an integer so  I have generated `TextChanged` Event Handler in that I have `CompareValidator` as follows

```
void txtControl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Log = new StringBuilder();
    CompareValidator validateTextBox = new CompareValidator();
    validateTextBox.Operator = ValidationCompareOperator.DataTypeCheck;
    validateTextBox.Type = ValidationDataType.Integer;
    validateTextBox.ControlToValidate = "txt1";
    string Message = validateTextBoxNumber.ErrorMessage;
 }
```

The event txtControl_TextChanged is firing but if a non-integer is passed it is not throwing an error message.

My questions are

1. How to validate the entered input is integer or non integer
2. In the example I'm giving the textbox id directly, how can I pass it
   dynamically

Comment: client side validation or serverside?

Comment: then why `jquery` tag here.. Its of no use!

Comment: From your code i see your CompareValidator object is **validateTextBoxNumber** but everywhere you are using **validateTextBox**  is it a typo?

Comment: Sorry,it was just a mistake, do see now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can process validation using javascript if client side validation is enough. Or else a server side validation like the following without using [`compareValidator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e303tf05.aspx).

```
void txtControl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtBox = sender as  TextBox; 
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox.Text) && txtBox.Text.All(Char.IsDigit))
    {
        //Throw error message
    }
}
```

Update:

Since `txtControl_TextChanged` is the event registered for each dynamic TextBox, it will triggered when corresponding event occur. hence from the `sender` we can easily validate the textbox as mentioned in the snippet. ie., `TextBox txtBox = sender as  TextBox;`

you can use your own method also, like a similar way:

```
void txtControl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Log = new StringBuilder();
    TextBox txtBox = sender as  TextBox; 
    CompareValidator validateTextBox = new CompareValidator();
    validateTextBox.Operator = ValidationCompareOperator.DataTypeCheck;
    validateTextBox.Type = ValidationDataType.Integer;
    validateTextBox.ControlToValidate = txtBox ;
    string Message = validateTextBoxNumber.ErrorMessage;
 }
```

Comment: I wan the `txtControl` is generated dynamically, how can I get that particular texbox @un-lucky

Comment: I even want to accept even if it is a `dot(.)`, as I haven't addressed before it is not allowing, What should be done to accept `dot` @un-lucky

Answer (score 0):

Now because you have tagged `jQuery` to this question, I have a `jQuery` solution to your problem.

I am validating the textbox for only integer input.

Change You code behind as below:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    TextBox txtControl = new TextBox();
    txtControl.ID = "txt" + i;
    txtControl.cssClass = "validate"
}
```

add the following Script tags to your front end:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".validate").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57 || e.which == 46)) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/38nn3rdx/1/
The above function wont allow text input.

Comment: Remove the text changed event from your textbox. Also remove the autopostback=true. You dont need to do a postback with my solution. Just add the above code in script tag of your front end file.

Comment: Validating for integer values from code behind wont be a efficient practice as this will give a postback every time you change the text. Client side scripting is the best solution for validation

Comment: I'm generating the controls code behind and my `textbox ids` differ from one and another.So have to call dynamically by sending the textbox id @Rajan Goswami

Comment: No problem... Assign a common class to all the dynamically created textboxes. You can do this by using `txt.CssClass = "validate"`. The rest will be taken care by my modified code. Please verify.

Comment: Can you provide a sample code or fiddle bcoz I have tried it but not working @Rajan Goswami

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have modified my code plz do as explained. A JSFiddle is also attached

Comment: dot?? Sorry.. i didnt get you . Please explain

Comment: Tq, I did it @Rajan Goswami

Answer (score 0):

please try this way:
1) write below scripting function in your page like below

```
$(".numeric").bind("keypress", function (event) {
        if (event.charCode != 0) {
            var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]+$");
            var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
            if (!regex.test(key)) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

step 2)  add css class for textbox. like

```
<input type="text" id="textboxid" class="numeric" />
```

so this will allowed only numeric values